# Error Message not displayed in popup

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

Hello I have a problem with the following code. The Validator works correctly and everything is fine, my only problem is that the error messages for the validation are not displayed. Am I missing something or the problem is with the popup?

```
<rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true" height="280" width="200" resizeable="true" onmaskclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()">                   
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Simple popup panel" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;"> X </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>
 <h:form id="newmssform">
    <table class="position">
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h:outputText class="output_text" value="New MSS Name:"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h:inputText id="mssusernamefield" value="#{NetworkBean.newMss}">
               <f:validator validatorId="NewMssValidator"/>
               <f:attribute name="mssaddressfield" value="#{mssaddressfield}"/>
             </h:inputText>
             <h:message for="mssusernamefield" errorClass="errors"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h:message for="mssusernamefield" errorClass="errors"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h:outputText class="output_text" value="IP Address:"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h:inputText id="mssaddressfield" value="#{NetworkBean.address}" binding="#{mssaddressfield}"/>
             <h:message for="mssaddressfield" errorClass="errors"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h:outputText class="output_text" value="User:"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
              <h:inputText id="mssuserfield" value="#{NetworkBean.mssUser}" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h:outputText class="output_text" value="Password:"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h:inputSecret id="msspwdfield" value="#{NetworkBean.mssUserPass}" />
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <a4j:commandButton style="border-radius: 5px; color: #FF6E00; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 5px;" value="Add New MSS"render="table,mss_table,oldIP" action="#{NetworkBean.addNewMss()}" />                                                             
          </td>
       </tr>           
</table>
```

Here is the validator:

```
public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) throws ValidatorException {

        String mssName = o.toString();
        UIInput addressComponent = (UIInput)uic.getAttributes().get("mssaddressfield");
        String address = addressComponent.getSubmittedValue().toString();
        UIInput userNameComponent = (UIInput) uic.getAttributes().get("mssaddressfield");
        String userName = userNameComponent.getSubmittedValue().toString();
        UIInput passwordComponent = (UIInput) uic.getAttributes().get("mssaddressfield");
        String password = passwordComponent.getSubmittedValue().toString();
        if(mssName.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty() || userName.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()){
            addressComponent.setValid(false);
            userNameComponent.setValid(false);
            passwordComponent.setValid(false);
            throw new ValidatorException(
                 new FacesMessage("Error!")); 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my prediction your `message` not rerender ontime
for `h:message` change code like below example

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
    <h:message for="mssusernamefield" errorClass="errors"/>
<a4j:outputPanel>
```

this may help you

Comment: also check @makhiel possibility

Answer (score 0):

[FacesMessage](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) consists of two Strings: summary and detail. When you call `new FacesMessage("Error!")` you're setting up the summary.

[h:message](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/message.html)'s default behaviour is to show the detail, but not the summary. You can either tell it to show the summary: `showSummary="true"` or provide the detail in the FacesMessage: `new FacesMessage("Error!", "Validation produced an error.")`